How get email (gmail account) for Playwright through imap configuration (typescript)
My goal is to read emails during Playwright tests
I follow https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs?hl=en documentation
I save credentials.json from ID clients OAuth 2.0 but an error raised
What am I missing?
I run example with 'node .'
But
Error: The provided keyfile does not define a valid
redirect URI. There must be at least one redirect URI defined, and this sample
assumes it redirects to 'http://localhost:3000/oauth2callback'.  Please edit
your keyfile, and add a 'redirect_uris' section.  For example:

"redirect_uris": [
  "http://localhost:3000/oauth2callback"
]


Please share a [mcve] of the code and your package.json. Playwright seems unsuitable for automating Gmail's UI in a test--I'd use Gmail's API or an API wrapper library to retrieve emails if you're trying to ensure that an email went through during a PW test.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
